# json javascript, display posts under category

Tags: javascript, json

I have a list of posts and want to display the posts in a list (li) under each category its associated with, the problem is that I'm getting a blank and is not adding the category or list..  let me know what i'm doing wrong

I want the list to look like this

1. Category 
   post
   post
   post
   post

   ```
   function recentPosts(data) {
      "use strict";

       $.each(data.posts, function(key, val) {

       var output = ' <div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos" id=" ' + val.slug + ' " data-title="Panel fixed positioning">';

       output += '<div data-role="header" class="ui-nodisc-icon" data-add-back-btn="true" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-back-btn-text="">';
       output += '<h1> ' + val.title + '</h1>';

       output += '<p class="company-name"> company name </p>';
       output += '<a href="#benefits-facts" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-home">  </a> </div>';

       output += '<div data-role="content" id="health-care-hc-plans-postlist" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth"> ';

       output += '<ul  data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search..." >';

   // $.each(data.posts, function(key, val) {

   //     if(v.categories.slug === val.categories.slug) { 
   //     output += '<li>';
   //     output += '<a href="#' + val.slug + '">';
   //     output += '<h3>' + val.title + "</h3>";
   //     output += '</a>';
   //     output += '</li>';
   //     }

   // }); //go through each post

       output += '</ul> </div> ';

       output += ' <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"> <h4> <a href="#info" data-transition="pop"> &copy; 2017 Michael F. Yates & Company, Inc. </a> </h4> </div>';

       output += '</div> ';

   }); //go through each post

   //$('#quick-facts').after(output);
   $('#newsletter2').after(output);
   }




    recentPosts(data);


   recentPosts({  
      "status":"ok",
      "count":10,
      "count_total":44,
      "pages":5,
      "posts":[  
         {  
            "id":185,
            "type":"benefits",
            "slug":"abbreviations-used",
            "status":"publish",
            "title":"Abbreviations Used",
            "title_plain":"Abbreviations Used",
            "content":"",
            "excerpt":"",
            "date":"2016-12-09 05:30:55",
            "modified":"2016-12-19 00:35:50",
            "categories":[  
               {  
                  "id":12,
                  "slug":"abbreviations-used",
                  "title":"Abbreviations Used",
                  "description":"",
                  "parent":0,
                  "post_count":1
               }
            ],
            "tags":[  

            ],
            "author":{  
               "id":5,
               "slug":"brodie",
               "name":"brodie",
               "first_name":"",
               "last_name":"",
               "nickname":"brodie",
               "url":"",
               "description":""
            },
            "comments":[  

            ],
            "attachments":[  

            ],
            "comment_count":0,
            "comment_status":"closed",
            "custom_fields":{  

            }
         },
         {  
            "id":184,
            "type":"benefits",
            "slug":"hc-flexible-spending-fsa-contributions",
            "status":"publish",
            "title":"HC Flexible Spending (FSA) Contributions",
            "title_plain":"HC Flexible Spending (FSA) Contributions",
            "content":"",
            "excerpt":"",
            "date":"2016-12-09 05:30:01",
            "modified":"2016-12-09 05:30:01",
            "categories":[  
               {  
                  "id":11,
                  "slug":"health-care-hc-plans",
                  "title":"Health Care (HC) Plans",
                  "description":"",
                  "parent":0,
                  "post_count":1
               }
            ],
            "tags":[  

            ],
            "author":{  
               "id":5,
               "slug":"brodie",
               "name":"brodie",
               "first_name":"",
               "last_name":"",
               "nickname":"brodie",
               "url":"",
               "description":""
            },
            "comments":[  

            ],
            "attachments":[  

            ],
            "comment_count":0,
            "comment_status":"closed",
            "custom_fields":{  

            }
         },
         {  
            "id":182,
            "type":"benefits",
            "slug":"dcfsa-married",
            "status":"publish",
            "title":"DCFSA Married",
            "title_plain":"DCFSA Married",
            "content":"",
            "excerpt":"",
            "date":"2016-12-09 05:24:05",
            "modified":"2016-12-09 05:24:05",
            "categories":[  
               {  
                  "id":23,
                  "slug":"dependent-care-fsa-dcfsa",
                  "title":"Dependent Care FSA (DCFSA)",
                  "description":"",
                  "parent":4,
                  "post_count":2
               }
            ],
            "tags":[  

            ],
            "author":{  
               "id":5,
               "slug":"brodie",
               "name":"brodie",
               "first_name":"",
               "last_name":"",
               "nickname":"brodie",
               "url":"",
               "description":""
            },
            "comments":[  

            ],
            "attachments":[  

            ],
            "comment_count":0,
            "comment_status":"closed",
            "custom_fields":{  

            }
         },
         {  
            "id":181,
            "type":"benefits",
            "slug":"what-is-a-dcfsa",
            "status":"publish",
            "title":"What is a DCFSA",
            "title_plain":"What is a DCFSA",
            "content":"",
            "excerpt":"",
            "date":"2016-12-09 05:23:45",
            "modified":"2016-12-09 05:23:45",
            "categories":[  
               {  
                  "id":23,
                  "slug":"dependent-care-fsa-dcfsa",
                  "title":"Dependent Care FSA (DCFSA)",
                  "description":"",
                  "parent":4,
                  "post_count":2
               }
            ],
            "tags":[  

            ],
            "author":{  
               "id":5,
               "slug":"brodie",
               "name":"brodie",
               "first_name":"",
               "last_name":"",
               "nickname":"brodie",
               "url":"",
               "description":""
            },
            "comments":[  

            ],
            "attachments":[  

            ],
            "comment_count":0,
            "comment_status":"closed",
            "custom_fields":{  

            }
         },
         {  
            "id":180,
            "type":"benefits",
            "slug":"eligible-tax-exempt-employer",
            "status":"publish",
            "title":"Eligible Tax-Exempt Employer",
            "title_plain":"Eligible Tax-Exempt Employer",
            "content":"",
            "excerpt":"",
            "date":"2016-12-09 05:20:11",
            "modified":"2016-12-09 05:20:11",
            "categories":[  
               {  
                  "id":22,
                  "slug":"small-business-hc-tax-credit",
                  "title":"Small Business HC Tax Credit",
                  "description":"",
                  "parent":11,
                  "post_count":3
               }
            ],
            "tags":[  

            ],
            "author":{  
               "id":5,
               "slug":"brodie",
               "name":"brodie",
               "first_name":"",
               "last_name":"",
               "nickname":"brodie",
               "url":"",
               "description":""
            },
            "comments":[  

            ],
            "attachments":[  

            ],
            "comment_count":0,
            "comment_status":"closed",
            "custom_fields":{  

            }
         },
         {  
            "id":179,
            "type":"benefits",
            "slug":"small-employer",
            "status":"publish",
            "title":"Small Employer",
            "title_plain":"Small Employer",
            "content":"",
            "excerpt":"",
            "date":"2016-12-09 05:19:45",
            "modified":"2016-12-09 05:19:45",
            "categories":[  
               {  
                  "id":22,
                  "slug":"small-business-hc-tax-credit",
                  "title":"Small Business HC Tax Credit",
                  "description":"",
                  "parent":11,
                  "post_count":3
               }
            ],
            "tags":[  

            ],
            "author":{  
               "id":5,
               "slug":"brodie",
               "name":"brodie",
               "first_name":"",
               "last_name":"",
               "nickname":"brodie",
               "url":"",
               "description":""
            },
            "comments":[  

            ],
            "attachments":[  

            ],
            "comment_count":0,
            "comment_status":"closed",
            "custom_fields":{  

            }
         },
         {  
            "id":178,
            "type":"benefits",
            "slug":"what-is-the-tax-credit",
            "status":"publish",
            "title":"What is the Tax Credit",
            "title_plain":"What is the Tax Credit",
            "content":"",
            "excerpt":"",
            "date":"2016-12-09 05:19:17",
            "modified":"2016-12-09 05:19:17",
            "categories":[  
               {  
                  "id":22,
                  "slug":"small-business-hc-tax-credit",
                  "title":"Small Business HC Tax Credit",
                  "description":"",
                  "parent":11,
                  "post_count":3
               }
            ],
            "tags":[  

            ],
            "author":{  
               "id":5,
               "slug":"brodie",
               "name":"brodie",
               "first_name":"",
               "last_name":"",
               "nickname":"brodie",
               "url":"",
               "description":""
            },
            "comments":[  

            ],
            "attachments":[  

            ],
            "comment_count":0,
            "comment_status":"closed",
            "custom_fields":{  

            }
         },
         {  
            "id":177,
            "type":"benefits",
            "slug":"affordable-care-act-hdhp",
            "status":"publish",
            "title":"Affordable Care Act HDHP",
            "title_plain":"Affordable Care Act HDHP",
            "content":"",
            "excerpt":"",
            "date":"2016-12-09 05:17:54",
            "modified":"2016-12-09 05:17:54",
            "categories":[  
               {  
                  "id":21,
                  "slug":"high-deductible-health-plans-hdhp",
                  "title":"High-Deductible Health Plans (HDHP)",
                  "description":"",
                  "parent":11,
                  "post_count":4
               }
            ],
            "tags":[  

            ],
            "author":{  
               "id":5,
               "slug":"brodie",
               "name":"brodie",
               "first_name":"",
               "last_name":"",
               "nickname":"brodie",
               "url":"",
               "description":""
            },
            "comments":[  

            ],
            "attachments":[  

            ],
            "comment_count":0,
            "comment_status":"closed",
            "custom_fields":{  

            }
         },
         {  
            "id":176,
            "type":"benefits",
            "slug":"hdhp-max-out-of-pocket",
            "status":"publish",
            "title":"HDHP Max. Out-of-Pocket",
            "title_plain":"HDHP Max. Out-of-Pocket",
            "content":"",
            "excerpt":"",
            "date":"2016-12-09 05:17:30",
            "modified":"2016-12-09 05:17:30",
            "categories":[  
               {  
                  "id":21,
                  "slug":"high-deductible-health-plans-hdhp",
                  "title":"High-Deductible Health Plans (HDHP)",
                  "description":"",
                  "parent":11,
                  "post_count":4
               }
            ],
            "tags":[  

            ],
            "author":{  
               "id":5,
               "slug":"brodie",
               "name":"brodie",
               "first_name":"",
               "last_name":"",
               "nickname":"brodie",
               "url":"",
               "description":""
            },
            "comments":[  

            ],
            "attachments":[  

            ],
            "comment_count":0,
            "comment_status":"closed",
            "custom_fields":{  

            }
         },
         {  
            "id":175,
            "type":"benefits",
            "slug":"hdhp-min-deductibles",
            "status":"publish",
            "title":"HDHP Min. Deductibles",
            "title_plain":"HDHP Min. Deductibles",
            "content":"",
            "excerpt":"",
            "date":"2016-12-09 05:17:01",
            "modified":"2016-12-09 05:17:01",
            "categories":[  
               {  
                  "id":21,
                  "slug":"high-deductible-health-plans-hdhp",
                  "title":"High-Deductible Health Plans (HDHP)",
                  "description":"",
                  "parent":11,
                  "post_count":4
               }
            ],
            "tags":[  

            ],
            "author":{  
               "id":5,
               "slug":"brodie",
               "name":"brodie",
               "first_name":"",
               "last_name":"",
               "nickname":"brodie",
               "url":"",
               "description":""
            },
            "comments":[  

            ],
            "attachments":[  

            ],
            "comment_count":0,
            "comment_status":"closed",
            "custom_fields":{  

            }
         }
      ],
      "query":{  
         "ignore_sticky_posts":true,
         "callback":"recentPosts"
      }
   });
   ```

Comment: Your output variable is a local variable of function iterating over data.posts and is not visible during calling $('#newsletter2').after(output);

Comment: are you saying ( var output ) needs to be outside of $.each

Comment: I got it to output by adding " var output " before the function call,  one other problem that I have is... if I call " val.categoreies.slug" I get undefined

Comment: does anybody know why I'm getting  Undefined when I try to get the value of val.categories.slug

Comment: Categories is an array, so you should use index, for example: val.categories[0].slug